# How to build a regular expression for nested search conditions

Tags: .net, regex

I need to build a regular expression for matching something like this:

> "PQR AND XYZ OR(ABC OR LMN)"

please help me to achieve this!

Comment: I'm sorry. My crystal ball is at the cleaners at the moment, so I need some more detail, please. Which regex engine are you using? What is the desired output? What exactly are the rules for matching that you want to implement?

Comment: .Net Regex engine is to be used here.The input will be in this format and it should check a string "Hello PQR,XYZ but where is ABC" and let me know if it matches the search expression provided.For the above searchstring the output will be TRUE according to the expression provided as "PQR AND XYZ OR(ABC OR LMN)"...

Answer (score 4):

1. It is **impossible** for regular expressions to correctly match nesting.
   For that, you need a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_parentheses).
2. I see that in your comment, you mentioned you will be using .NET.
   The "regular expression" library in .NET is actually **more powerful** than what people normally call "regular expressions" in computer science.

   It **is** possible to use .NET Regexes to match nested parentheses using *balancing-group definitions*:

   ```
   \(
     (?>
         [^()]+
       |
         (?<DEPTH>\()
       |
         (?<-DEPTH>\))
     )*
     (?(DEPTH)(?!))
   \)
   ```

   For this pattern to work you'll need to ignore whitespaces.

   Just be aware that [this isn't available in every regular expression library and is not what regular expressions are defined to be in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages).